# Solving Lagrange System of Equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Given function $f(x,y)=x^2+xy+y^2$
on disc $x^2+y^2 = 1$

I get the LaGrange system of equations

$2x+y = 2xλ$

$2y+x = 2yλ$

$x^2+y^2 = 1$

I had many unsuccessful attempts but I remember being told that in general, setting all values of x,y,z to λ is the best way. How do you solve this problem to find all values x,y,z?

Comment: I suppose,in the second equation you mean $2y+x=2y \lambda$.

Comment: Yes, apologies.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first two equation we get,

$$(2-2\lambda)x=-y$$

$$(2-2\lambda)y=-x$$

We may safely assume $x \neq 0$ (and) or $y \neq 0$ otherwise $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and the third equation $x^2+y^2=1$ is not satisfied.

Dividing both equations above by each other we must have $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{y}{x}$ or $x=\pm y$. If $x=\pm y$ then $x^2+x^2=1$ from the third equation so $x,y=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the first for $y$ and plug into the second. Note that $x$ cannot be $0$, so we can divide by it.
$$2x(\lambda-1)=y\\2y(\lambda-1)=x\\4x(\lambda-1)^2=x\\ \lambda=\frac 32,\frac 12 \\x=\pm\frac {\sqrt 2}2, y=\pm\frac {\sqrt 2}2 \text { with the signs independent}$$

Comment: $4x(λ−1)^2=x$
Wont it simplify to 
$(λ−1)^2=1/4$ then  $(λ−1)=±1/2$ which means $λ=3/2$ and $λ=1/2$

Comment: No, but I missed the second root.  It should be $\lambda -1 = \pm \frac 12$